# Работа сервиса на Linux установленного на VirtualBox

Tags: c#, linux, virtualbox, service

На рабочую машину установлена Windows. В ней установлен VirtualBox c linux. В Linux я установил свой сервис который открывается через localhost:5000/odata Но с машины Windows я не могу зайти на свою службу по ip Linux машины 192.168.X.X:5000/odata/ Что только не делал уже((

Comment: Так и не понятно, что Вы уже делали. Вообще необходимо прокинуть порты в настройках виртуальной машины -> Сеть -> Проброс портов

Comment: Как именно это сделать ? Есть инструкция ?

Comment: Проверьте, чтобы сервис слушал адрес 0.0.0.0:5000, а не 127.0.0.1:5000 или localhost:5000, возможно из-за этого проблема.

Comment: https://losst.ru/probros-portov-virtualbox   OK GOOGLE

Comment: @insolor localhost резолвится локальным резольвером в 127.0.0.1, другими словами разницы нет, он будет недоступен с основной ОС. А сервис должен слушать как раз тот IP, который является виртуальным сетевым адаптером внутри VirtualBox.

Comment: @AlTheOne Проброс порта - здесь не единственное решение, можно методом маршрутизации. Если в таблицу маршрутизации прописать правильные маршруты, будет все работать, если обратиться по вдресу виртуальной машины. Вы же в локальной сети можете по айпишнику компа обратиться в любому компу, безо всякого проброса портов, вот и здесь то же самое. А проброс нужен только тогда, когда виртуалка подключена к освновному хосту через NAT.

Comment: @aepot Согласен. Но тот, кто задаёт подобные вопросы вряд ли вообще в таблицу маршрутизации полезет. Обозначил ему самый простой путь.